# Convert a vector of string to a vector of integer

Tags: r

The following works as expected:

```
> as.integer(c("2","3"))
[1] 2 3
```

but when I try (using the stringr package):

```
> str_split("55,66,77",",")
[[1]]
[1] "55" "66" "77"
> as.integer(str_split("55,66,77",","))
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

Is there any other way to convert a string of form "55,66,77" into the vector with those three numbers?
I'm a complete newbie and any hint to documentation about this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`str_split` returns a list. You have to access the correct list element:

```
as.integer(str_split("55,66,77",",")[[1]]) ## note the [[1]]
# [1] 55 66 77
```

Or you could use `unlist` to turn the complete list into a vector:

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit("55,66,77",",")))
# [1] 55 66 77
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was really fast. I thought lists were vectors.

Comment: Lists are (generic) vectors, but are not vectors that can be coerced to integer.

Comment: Just in case someone tries this solution, the function `str_split` is from the `stringr` package.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a vector of strings and want the values for each, `lapply` will iterate through the list:

```
v <- c("55,66,77", "1,2,3")
lapply(str_split(v, ','), as.integer)
## [[1]]
## [1] 55 66 77
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit("55,66,77",",")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `scan`? If all the data are comma separated integers to begin with, the result would be a vector of integers, eliminating the need to use `as.integer` later on.

```
x <- "55,66,77"
y <- scan(text = x, what = 0L, sep=",")
# Read 3 items
y
#  [1] 55 66 77
str(y)
#  int [1:3] 55 66 77
```

---

With multiple values, take your pick as to whether you want a single vector or a list of vectors:

```
v <- c("55,66,77", "1,2,3")
scan(text = v, what = 0L, sep=",")
# Read 6 items
# [1] 55 66 77  1  2  3
lapply(seq_along(v), function(z) scan(text = v[z], what = 0L, sep = ","))
# Read 3 items
# Read 3 items
# [[1]]
# [1] 55 66 77
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

---

Add `quiet = TRUE` to `scan` if you don't want the messages about how many values were read in....